# Solution for 404 error Using restful web services with json

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, tomcat

Hi I Created simple restful web services and using JSON for respone and storing information.when i run the service in tomcat 7.0 i got 404 error in browser

PLS help me to fix the error

**Service Class**

```
package com.login.service;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

//Path Reference to access this interface
@Path("/Sample")
public class OrdersService {


        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1009)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Returning the Response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
JSONObject userDetails = null;
try 
{
   userDetails.put("firstname", "Jagathesewaren");
```

you are invoking `put` method on `null`. Initialize `userDetails` object

```
JSONObject userDetails = new JSONObject();
try 
{
   userDetails.put("firstname", "Jagathesewaren");
```

Comment: Hi llya first thanks for ur reply i updated the code as u mentioned above but i got same error again

Comment: @JagathesewarenKuppuraj `NullPointer`? In which line?

Comment: TomCat ERROR i mentioned above

Comment: @JagathesewarenKuppuraj what error? Can you add stacktrace?

Comment: in browser i got HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error in tomcat mentioned above how to add stacktrace can u tell me

Comment: @JagathesewarenKuppuraj it is in browser. What did you get on server sude?

Comment: Oct 25, 2013 1:57:37 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObje
ct, and Java type class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject, and MIME media ty
pe application/xml was not found

Comment: @JagathesewarenKuppuraj this is new problem, with Jersey configuration. You can find solutions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777661/java-jersey-jettison-message-body-reader-exception. Also eead this article http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/