# Message body reader for Java class not found (non-Maven)

Tags: java, json, jersey

This is a slight variation to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777661/java-jersey-jettison-message-body-reader-exception/23189545?noredirect=1#comment35468861_23189545). I'm not using Maven but have the jersey-bundle-1.17.1 included in the classpath. It seems to include all the classes in jersey-json. However I also added jersey-json to classpath and WEB-INF/lib and get the same error. I'm POSTing json

```
{ to: 'John', company: 'Costo' }
```

Anything obvious?

Recipient is simple POJO with two string fields - to and company

```
@POST
@Path("/saveit")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response saveit(Recipient rec) {
         System.out.println(rec); 
         ....
}
```

But I still get the error:

```
Apr 20, 2014 8:17:23 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity    
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.company.guestbook.model.Recipient, and Java type class com.company.guestbook.model.Recipient, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
    The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
    application/json ->
      com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
      com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
      com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
    */* ->
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
      ...
```

Comment: Have you properly annotated your POJO?

Answer (score 0):

This should fail at compile time since your method implementation has no return object (i.e., it's a `void` return) but the method signature indicates that a `Response` object is returned. Your implementation simply prints the `Recipient` object to standard output (which is likely to end up in your container's log file).

I see you're not using Maven to manage your dependencies (which is fine) but have you added the Jersey required dependencies? For example, this [error report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594707/jersey-exception-severe-a-message-body-reader-for-java-class) looks similar to yours...

Comment: thanks. just added the missing ellipsis. avoiding cluttering with the irrelevant parts. the exception occures during the marshalling so we never get to the sysout.

Comment: @Fakeer - it's a lot easier to help you if you include the relevant code. Please do strip-down the example to the simplest proof-of-concept which shows the error you're encountering; otherwise, we are left guessing what the code might look like which triggers the error. And do also include the whole error...